# How did Arya get her dagger back from Sansa?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I am not sure how this plays out in the books as I haven't read them, but I just watched the last episode of *Game of Thrones* and it went down like this:

1. Arya gave her dagger to Sansa at the beginning of the episode before Sansa made her way to the crypt.
2. A whole lot of events went down.
3. Arya finds out she is supposedly meant to kill the Night King and goes full commando.
4. At some point after this moment we see the dagger still with Sansa, which is also verified by the fact that Tyrion saw it and was like "Yeah, cool, Valyrian Steel dagger! Let's rock it!".
5. Arya goes *Assassin's Creed* on the Night King's dead butt with the dagger.

Is there something I'm missing here or did the dagger just teleport between the two?

Comment: Un(directly)related: The series is far ahead of the books (_cough_ stop procrastinating GRRM _cough_), so even who read them don't know much. Also the showrunners kind of detached the series from the books, so its more or less a different story.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: GRRM said the book and the series have similar endings (https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/game-of-thrones-season-8-george-rr-martin-60-minutes) but you are right: knowing the books does not really help to know how the events unfold in the series.

Comment: Search for the moment she show the dagger to Tyrion. you should have enought light to see the obsidian blade. Really bigger and not curved like the dagger

Comment: There is 0 need to remove any more content from this title. Arya getting her dagger back from Sansa is in no way a spoiler. Any further edits would just render the question incredibly arbitrary.

Comment: "*goes full commando*" I don't know what that means where you come from, but in the UK that means discarding all underwear.  Which is not entirely unusual for GoT characters, of course, but not generally in the middle of a battle, and might be a bit chilly when winter has come.

Comment: right you are, in this sense she went full commando the previous episode.

Comment: ["Some fans thought that Arya gave the dagger to Sansa at the beginning of the episode. After the wights proved unstoppable, Arya told Sansa to go down to the crypts and to take the dagger to protect herself. We only see the hilt and can assume it’s the Valyrian steel dagger. But Sansa flashes the dagger to Tyrion in the crypts as they hide from the Wights and we see that it is dragonglass."](https://time.com/5579377/game-of-thrones-arya-kill-night-king/)

Answer (score 72):

The dagger Arya gave Sansa was a dragonglass dagger, not her dagger.

Comment: Hm, alright. I was left under the impression that Arya has no weapons left when she was tip-toeing around the mess hall with the walkers lurking around. And that is why she had to resolve to murking the one with her bare hands (which also didn't make much sense when I think about it...)

Comment: Ok, just saw it again and yes, she has some dragon glass broken spear

Comment: Ok, just saw it all again and I retract the question. I blame the shitty quality. What is dead may never die!

Comment: Or was it one of the ends of her broken "Sith Lord" staff?

Comment: _"I was left under the impression that Arya had no weapons left"_ A girl always has a weapon left.

Answer (score 14):

She gave her a dragonglass dagger, not the Valyrian steel dagger. See the below screenshot with brightness increased

[image: Arya gives Sansa a dragonglass dagger]

Comment: "with brightness increased" I'd like to see the whole episode again with brightness increased!

Comment: @carley, time to create a SuperUser question : "How to increase brightness and contrast in VLC?"

Comment: @Carley having been forewarned the whole episode was visually very dark, I watched it with the lights off. I didn't miss anything that way, and everything looked great :)

Answer (score 12):

My understanding was that Arya handed Sansa an ordinary dragonglass dagger before sending her to the crypts, not the Catspaw dagger.

Comment: "ordinary", "dragonglass" - that's a pair of adjectives I didn't expect to see together!

Comment: @MartinBonner There's literally a mountain of the stuff under Dragonstone, it's not exactly an obscure material.

Answer (score 5):

That's not her dagger. What she gives to Sansa is one of the weapons made from dragonglass in the forges of Winterfell.